# initializing pointers in OOP C-lang

Tags: c

trying to do object orientation in C, but I don't get it.

I want to have a struct with references to functions and itself. I have this before main, but the compiler complains. How do I work around it?
Compiler complains about:
"Initializer element is not constant", "unknown typename SENSOR_OBJECT"

```
void config_time_base(alt_u32, void*);
void init_measurement(QUEUE *q);
void read_accelerometerX(QUEUE *q);
void update(QUEUE *q);


typedef struct SENSOR_CLASS
{
   char description[80];
   alt_u32 x_origo;
   alt_u32 y_origo;
   alt_u32 time_base;
   QUEUE queue;
   QUEUE *q;
   void (*configure_time_base)(alt_u32, SENSOR_OBJECT*);
   void (*reset_samples_vector)(QUEUE*);
   void (*read_sensor)(QUEUE*);
   void (*update_graph)(QUEUE*);
   SENSOR_OBJECT* this;
}SENSOR_OBJECT;

QUEUE q1,q2,q3,q4,q5;
QUEUE* q11 = &q1;
SENSOR_OBJECT accelorometerX =
    {   "Accelerometer x",
        50, 50,1,q1,q11,
        config_time_base,
        init_measurement,
        read_accelerometerX,
        update,
        &accelorometerX
    };
```

Comment: What does the compiler complain about?

Comment: "Initializer element is not constant"
"unknown typename SENSOR_OBJECT"

Comment: Don't post essential information in comments. Please [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mention of `SENSOR_OBJECT` before `SENSOR_OBJECT` is actually defined:

```
   void (*configure_time_base)(alt_u32, SENSOR_OBJECT*); // <--- mentioned here
   SENSOR_OBJECT* this;                                  // <--- mentioned here
}SENSOR_OBJECT;                                          // <--- defined here
```

This is not allowed.

The easiest way out is to separate the typedef and the struct definition:

```
typedef struct SENSOR_CLASS SENSOR_OBJECT;
struct SENSOR_CLASS { ...
```

The `Initializer element is not constant` error tells you you cannot initialize a field with a thing which is not a constant expression. In order to fix this, write a function that allocates a `SENSOR_OBJECT` and assigns (*not* initializes) its fields from the function parameters. This would be your implementation of a *constructor*.

On a tangentially related note, it doesn't make much sense to keep a `this` pointer in each object. In order to access `this`, you would have to know the address of the object, but that address always equals `this`.

On a less related note, keeping function pointers in the struct is somewhat a waste of memory. Consider keeping them in a separate `vtable` object (one per class) and having a pointer to that `vtable` in each instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the typedef while defining the type. At the place you use the type alias, the compiler don't know it so replace with:

```
struct SENSOR_CLASS *this;
```

or you can make a forward declaration of your type, like:

```
typedef struct SENSOR_CLASS SENSOR_OBJECT;

struct SENSOR_CLASS {
    SENSOR_OBJECT *this;
};
```

Comment: "Initializer element is not computable at loadtime"